# Will a collection with a total size exceeding 85kB be put on the large-object-heap?

Tags: .net, memory-management

I have a question about about when objects get put into the small- vs large-object-heap.

I have two string with size smaller than 85kB which I add to a collection, such as a List. The combined size of the strings exceeds 85kB.

Will this collection be treated as part of the small-object-heap or as part of the large object-heap? I think it will be SOH but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collection is a `List<TReference>` of any size then it is SOH. If the collection is a `TReference[]` with a size <= 20k elements at 32 bits, or 10k elements at 64 bits (the size of a reference at 32bits is 4 bytes, at 64bits is 8 bytes), the it is SOH.

The size of an object isn't calculate based on object X + all the objects referenced by object X, but simply by the "direct" size of X.

Why the difference between `List<TReference>` and `TReference[]`? Because arrays (technically single dimensional, 0-base indexed arrays) are the only variable length data type directly supported by the IL language. Nearly all the other collection types are simply a reference to a `T[]` array (or to a bunch of `T[]` arrays) plus some supporting numeric fields. So for example a `List<T>` is a reference to a `T[]` plus a `int Length`.

The point of SOH vs LOH is "how much fast would be to move it around memory"? Clearly:

```
public class MySmallClass
{
    public byte[] WithABigObject = new byte[1024*1024];
}
```

While moving the `BigObject` (the byte array) would be very slow, moving the `MySmallClass` (that is simply composed by a reference) is very fast, because it has the size of a reference :-)

Note that in C# creating objects that aren't arrays with a size >= 85k is quite difficult, because, as I've said, between the types that are directly supported by the IL language, only the array has a variable size. Every other type has a fixed size and is quite small. You would need to make a class with 22k `int` inside to make a LOH without an array :-)

An example of a LOH object without arrays: https://ideone.com/OuVkEs . It is based on multilevel `KeyValuePair<,>` (a `struct`) that at the lowest level use `Guid` (the biggest commonly used `struct`). The resulting `BigGuid128k` is a `struct` of 128k. By including it in your class, your class will become a LOH :-)

Comment: You can easily build a huge struct, but of course that's rarely a good idea.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes... by using `KeyValuePair<,>` recursively it is possible... But still it is a long way up to 85k :-) And it would be the most stupid idea I've ever seen.